# error while install pcap using "npm install pcap"

Tags: node.js, pcap

I am developing a packet capture application in nodejs.

When I issue the command `npm install pcap`, I have this error:

[image: Error Screen]

Can someone help me to solve? Thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap/issues/196

Comment: Thank this help me a lot. `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo aptitude install nodejs
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev git
npm install https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap.git`. Check this link [link](https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap/issues/196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this ([enter link description here](https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap/issues/196)) helped me a lot. 
`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo aptitude install nodejs
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev git
npm install https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap.git`. 
Now It is working find.